# Struck up with Design issue

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

Please see the Image below and you will get the context related to my question .

[image]

The web site is a Site for talented  Photographers where they can Upload Pictures and allow others to see what they have taken .

I am struck Up in my work , due to a design Issue .

A user ( No registration required ) can open my Website and Upload  details like Name , Mobile , description , Image  (The same user can upload different images ) at which mobile number  is mantadatory field . so while Uploading the Picture , i am appending it with Mobile Number + FileName.jpg , and the Image  will be stored inside a folder inside my server and the remaining details like mobile num , desc , name --etc will be Stored  inside MYSQL Database .  (This is one part and its completed )

2nd part is 
On Page start up  , i am getting all the images (latest 20 fixed ) from the that folder and showing it on the page .

So when any  user clicks on a particulr  Image  i need to show the deetails like Desc , Name , ---etc , so on  onclick  event of that image ,  i am picking up the Mobile number  from the  image  clicked and making a search in Database . (Now there is  a problem here )  that is  ,  A same user ( that is with same mobile number ) can upload different pictures to the web site , so the search using the  Mobile number will give me many results .

The picture name format is 83746787695iokI.jpg  .

I am ready to chAange any format , so please tell how this can be solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a filename `83746787695iokI.jpg` you should be able to parse the uploader phone number and the original filename, then query your table of photos using those values. A regex for that could be:

```
/^([0-9]{11})(.+)\.jpg$/
```

Having said that, you should consider assigning a unique identifier to each photo and use it to name your saved files. An id column in MySQL could look like this:

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

After insertion, get the id of the new row (`LAST_INSERT_ID()` in MySQL) and save your file with its name being `#{id}.jpg`.

Note that the autoincremented id is a predictable integer, your filenames will be `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, etc. A simple script can be used to download all images from your server.  To avoid that, name your files using a random generated unique string instead, e.g. UUID. Store that string in a new column in your table and use that to identify your photos.

Answer (score 0):

It is is you can use a different primary key.
You may use autonumber field or you can use timestamps while storing an image in database :)

and for design i suggest you to go http://www.dynamicdrive.com/

Regards Red

Comment: I  would not like to go for timestamps  , thinking about autonumber , could you please provide more details on autonumber  ( Incase the application grows upto lakhs )